# What would be the center of the curvature?

Tags: geometry

[image][image]An arc is drawn with starting point, ending point & midpoint being: $A(0.1375,0)$, $B(0.1375,0.22)$, $C(0.15,0.11)$ respectively in Cartesian coordinate system.What would be the method to find out the center of the circle of which the arc is a part? 
After finding the center point,what would be x coordinate of point D?

Comment: Please note that flags (especially moderator-only "other" flags) are not an appropriate way to get attention to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The perpendicular bisector of any chord of a circle passes through the center.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a circle of radius $r$ centered at the point $(x_0, y_0)$ is defined by $(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = r^2$.  Plug in the three known $(x, y)$ values along the arc.

- Point A: $(0.19 - x_0)^2 + (0 - y_0)^2 = r^2$
- Point B: $(0.1375 - x_0)^2 + (0.22 - y_0)^2 = r^2$
- Point C: $(0.15 - x_0)^2 + (0.11 - y_0)^2 = r^2$

Three equations for three unknowns.

Comment: @Dan-by using these equations the coordinates are found as (0.0398375,0.11). How these can be used to find the x coordinate of a point on that arc if the y coordinate is known?

Comment: @user202851 Just plug in the values of $x_0, y_0, r$ and $y$ into $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$ and solve for $x$ (you should get two results for $x$ as the line at $y=0.02$ intersects the circle twice.)

Comment: @all-By using the formula above, the center of circle is at (0.627775,0.11). Sorry for the previous wrong answer! As the center would be at x=0.62775 i.e. far right to the arc,i think it should not be so.